# Parse "Certificate Policies" extension

Tags: c#, certificate

I have a certificate (`X509Certificate2`) in my app, and I can enumerate all certificate's extensions. One of those extensions is Certificate Policies, with OID 2.5.29.32. This extension is supposed to be just a sequence of OID's, and I need to search for specific OID's there. The problem is that this extension is coded as DER octet string. How can I get to the OID inside that I'm interested in? Do I have to manually parse a DER octet string? How can I do that?

EDIT: I'm going to see what Bouncy Castle has to offer, but I'm wondering if there is a ready solution in .NET framework. Framework parses certificates and other DER structures, so there might be DER decoder built in.

BOUNTY: I have found a solution for me, but I'm looking for improvements. Bounty goes to other solution if it satisfies one or more of the following, sorted by relevance:

1. it uses standard .NET library functions
2. it uses mature or proven source code or library, smaller than Bouncy Castle (I need only parsing, not the all the rest)
3. it merely improves on the code I already have, in a matter that I find worthy

BUMP: Bounty expires today. If no one else provides an answer it'll go to GalacticJello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a year ago. 
I found a small library that helped me a lot ([site](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/index.html)). This library transforms the file key in xml (using a .exe) and then we could read it on C#.

I didn't liked to transform my key in XML. I asked for the library's developer to use the opensource code in my project, fortunately he accepted. So I built a [fork](https://gist.github.com/makah/4f95dcf8d0d028ca366f6ac1c13a5d4e) that do exactly what I needed.

<strike>After a long time, I have found another implementation in Mono project, avaiable [here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid0005D522A9B5E25FEF70E4D9DA37822E5E9725EC.aspx).</strike>

A helper class that uses CryptoLib [here](https://gist.github.com/makah/2c2ad477c05099add3f99c81c6cd71ec) and an example here:

```
public IRegistryService Connect(String name, RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey, X509Certificate2 acsCertificate) {
  if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) || (acsCertificate == null) || (privateKey == null))
    throw new ArgumentException("....");

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Credential.identifier))
    throw new ACSLoginFailureException("....");

  byte[] challenge = this.acs.getChallenge(name);      
  byte[] answer = new byte[0];
  try {
    answer = Crypto.GenerateAnswer(challenge, privateKey, acsCertificate);
  }
  catch (CryptographicException e) {
    throw new ACSLoginFailureException("....", e);
  }

  bool connect = this.acs.loginByCertificate(name, answer, out this.credential, out leaseTime);      

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah Mono. I thought they just clone the existing functionality, but apparently they extend it too.

Comment: Both links are dead now to your solutions. Could you please include it here as code, editing your answer.

Comment: @Makah I would suggest putting actual code here in the answer, for posterity. Also your example link is broken at the end of the last sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get a string representation using `extension.Format()`:

```
foreach (X509Extension extension in certificate.Extensions)
{
    if(extension.Oid.FriendlyName.Equals("Certificate Policies"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(extension.Format(true));
    }
}
```

The output I got looked likes this:

```
[1]Certificate Policy:
    Policy Identifier=2.16.356.100.2.3
```

This is exactly what appears when viewing the certificate using the `certmgr.msc` tool.  This tells me the class of the certificate as defined by the CCA India.  For example, this is a Class 3 certificate.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've done it (but read also the update below). Bouncy Castle is used for parsing ASN.1 DER.

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;

string GetMeTheOidThatIWant(byte[] certificate)
{
    X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
    X509Certificate cert1 = parser.ReadCertificate(certificate);

    X509Extension certPolicies =
        cert1.CertificateStructure.TbsCertificate.Extensions.GetExtension(X509Extensions.CertificatePolicies);

    DerSequence seq = certPolicies.GetParsedValue() as DerSequence;

    foreach (Asn1Encodable seqItem in seq)
    {
        DerSequence subSeq = seqItem as DerSequence;
        if (subSeq == null)
            continue;

        foreach (Asn1Encodable subSeqItem in subSeq)
        {
            DerObjectIdentifier oid = subSeqItem as DerObjectIdentifier;
            if (oid == null)
                continue;

            if (ThisIsTheOneIWant(oid))
                return oid.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I stumbled recently to function [CryptFormatObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379939(v=vs.85).aspx) that supports Certificate Policies OID (`szOID_CERT_POLICIES`). Did not try the function, but it looks useful. And 5 minutes later I notice it's exactly what is described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36349758) by Kinjal Dixit.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to reduce the code needed to parse ASN.1, you could have a peek at the LCLib portion of the [ASN.1 Editor project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-1-Editor).

It is a simple ASN.1 processor library.

Using the sample DER encoded test string of "test1@rsa.com" :

16 0d 74 65 73 74 31 40 72 73 61 2e 63 6f 6d

```
using (var stm = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 0x16, 0x0d, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x31, 0x40, 0x72, 0x73, 0x61, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d })) 
{ 
    Asn1Parser parser = new Asn1Parser(); 
    parser.LoadData(stm); 
    var decoded = parser.ToString(); 
}
```

Gives the formatted output:

> Offset| Len |LenByte|
>
> ======+======+=======+====
>
> ```
>  0|    13|      1| IA5 STRING : 'test1@rsa.com'
> ```

You can walk the tree, and process the nodes as you wish.

Comment: I stumbled upon this page while searching for a solution. After fiddling with given code I've made a code that works. But given code is coupled with the rest of the project, which is oriented to showing data in the editor. It works, but it's not ideal. Thank you for your answer, but Mono trumps a page on CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the Certificate Policies field has a non-standard format.  Its contents are not defined by the IETF RFCs, but by the CA Browser Forum.  It's used to indicate Extended Validation certificates.

Here's that field from "www.bankofamerica.com"

Sequence:
     ObjectIdentifier: 2.5.29.32 certificatePolicies
     OctetString: (48, 59, 48, 57, 6, 11, 96, 134, 72, 1, 134, 248, 69, 1, 7, 23, 6, 48, 42, 48, 40, 6, 8, 43, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 2, 1, 22, 28, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 118, 101, 114, 105, 115, 105, 103, 110, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 114, 112, 97)
      OctetString as ASCII: '0;09\x06\x0b`\x86H\x01\x86\xf8E\x01\x07\x17\x060*0(\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x02\x01\x16\x1chttps://www.verisign.com/rpa'

This was dumped with a small program using the Python library "pyasn1", which can parse DER and PEM format data.  The problem is that the value of CertificatePolicies is that it's of ASN1 type "OctetString", which means it's just raw bytes to ASN1.  Most other fields are useful types like PrintableText, Integer, or Date, but not this one.

RFC2527 from 1999 just hand-waves on this; there's a place where that info was supposed to be filled in, but wasn't.  The OpenSSL doc (http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html) says "The syntax of raw extensions is governed by the extension code: it can for example contain data in multiple sections. The correct syntax to use is defined by the extension code itself: check out the certificate policies extension for an example." The CAB Forum EV Certificate Guidelines (http://www.cabforum.org/EV_Certificate_Guidelines.pdf) define what goes in that field (see Appendix B), but refer to RFC3280 for the format.  RFC3280 says "The certificate policies extension contains a sequence of one or more policy information terms, each of which consists of an object identifier (OID) and optional qualifiers.  Optional qualifiers, which MAY be present, are not expected to change the definition of the policy." So it's supposed to be an ASN1 Sequence of items containing OIDs and "optional qualifiers". But that's not what EV certs actually contain.

As for the allowed OIDs for EV certs, there's no public official list. The CA Browser Forum has a private list it shares with its members. But look in Wikipedia for an unofficial one.

More later when I figure out the format.

Comment: More info: the raw OctetString following an OID of 2.5.29.32 (certificatePolicies) is DER-encoded. Run it through a DER decoder, and you'll get the structure that contains the cert policies.  This is just lame.  ASN1 has a nice way to express a tree, and this is just broken.